# RoR Setting Windows environment

Tags: windows, ruby-on-rails-3, ide, rubymine

I'm a rails developer and I always programmed on linux environment using Netbeans and RVM.
I would like to try a migration on windows using the IDE rubymine that I've already downloaded. Is there any tutorial or instructions to set up  the environment for people like me that are approaching on Windows in Rails for the very first time? (installing ruby the gems etc ? ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a section on Windows instalation in the excellent [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec%3arails_installer_windows)

I also found this [blog](http://blog.dominicsayers.com/2011/01/21/howto-install-ruby-on-rails-on-windows-and-deploy-to-heroku/) entry that walks you the process step-by-step

When installing on Windows myself I used [this](http://tekpub.com/view/byob-rails/9) video tutorial from Tekpub, but you'll need to pay to access it.

Comment: I don't thing it's worth to pay for such things. However thanks, do you think it's more confortable Windows or Unix Enviroments for RoR ?

Comment: It's easier/better on Unix, I had problems with a number of gems on Windows and things like running Cucumber tests are an order of magnitude faster on Unix. If you have no choice though, it's possible to get by using Windows.

Comment: Ok tnx ... however, the 1st link you provided explain how to set unix enviroments and not userful for my purpose

Comment: In the blog you suggested, it says that ruby 1.9.2 "The default install of Ruby (1.9.2) is not compatible with the Heroku deployment widget." ... Is it still true ? Because I'm quite sure that I have an application up and running using that Ruby ver on heroku. Moreover, I think that in my env I should use that version, if it is true, do you suggest me to avoid the RailsInstaller all in one package that is mentioned on that blog ?

Comment: The first link should contain some Windows specific instructions at the top of the page under the heading "Rails Installer (Windows)"

Comment: I think the Heroku/1.9.2 problem is Windows specific. If you scroll to the bottom of the article it is further discussed in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you http://rubyinstaller.org/ or http://www.railsinstaller.org/

I did it on my machine and everything works fine, you can add later pik (a multi ruby manager)